# Calculating marginal effects of a lmer model with polynomial terms

Tags: r, lme4, effects

I am trying to quantify the effect size of variables in a mixed model using `lme4` but I can't seem to get it to work with a `poly()` function that creates a non-linear interaction between two variables.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(readr)

mydata <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HaydenSchilling/Example_code_and_data/master/example_data2.csv")

m1 <- lmer(CPUE.standardised ~ poly(cbind(X135_degree_winds.standardised, 
       X45_degree_winds.standardised), degree = 2) + 
       Estuary_Type * Drought_Months + (1|Estuary), data = mydata)

anova(m1)
summary(m1)

library(ggeffects)
ggpredict(m1, terms = "X135_degree_winds.standardised")
```

The last line gives the error:

> Error: Can't find column `cbind` in `.data`.
>   Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

I have tried both `ggeffects` and `sjPlot` packages but both run into issues with the `cbind` command or can not find the specified variable. If anyone has any solutions I would be very grateful!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the cbind? Can you post some data? We can't see your csv.

Comment: The cbind function lets the polynomial function create a interaction between the two terms as well as individual polynomial (non-linear) terms. You should be able to load the csv file with the code, I just tested it again. The idea is the two variables do not have linear responses but also interact.

Comment: I find it unlikely that cbind is doing what you imagine. Cerstinly the machinery in lmer or ggpredict is having difficulty with the local naming of terms. I don't disagree with the goal but I will observe that polynomial terms have difficulties that Frank Harrell addressed by using restricted cubic splines. If you went that route the code would look something like `rcs(var1,3)*rcs(var2,3) + ...`

Comment: @42- thanks, Following that the cbind might be unpredictable, I restructured the model (removing the cbind) and it is now possible to extract marginal effect values. The following model structure is equivalent to the first and gives identical results.
`m2 <- lmer(CPUE.standardised ~ poly(X135_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2) + 
             poly(X45_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2) +
             X135_degree_winds.standardised:X45_degree_winds.standardised+
             Estuary_Type * Drought_Months + (1|Estuary), data = mydata)

r.squaredGLMM(m2)
summary(m2)`

Comment: That makes sense to me. I think it would also be possible to make an interaction model with `poly(X135_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2)*poly(X45_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2)` as a single term which should have two extra degrees of freedom if i'm correct. Do avoid the temptation to interpret single coefficients.

Comment: @42- thanks, yes using that specification of the model is both simpler and has higher degrees of freedom. It also looks at interactions between the quadratic forms of the two variables not just the linear interaction. The model fit also improved using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the comments I got. The problem was with the `cbind` command I had in the polynomial. The solution was to change the model structure to not include `cbind`.

An equivalent model to the one in the original question is:

```
m2 <- lmer(CPUE.standardised ~ poly(X135_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2) + 
   poly(X45_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2) + 
   X135_degree_winds.standardised:X45_degree_winds.standardised+ 
   Estuary_Type * Drought_Months + (1|Estuary), data = mydata)
```

This then allows the calculation of the marginal effects.

An improved model structure was also suggested as:

```
poly(X135_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2)*
 poly(X45_degree_winds.standardised, degree = 2)
```